# VS code of " cd ~~~~~message" while running python code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Displaying of this message whenever I run a code slows down the system.

Why am I getting this message and how can I get rid of this message?

In the terminal window, it says

```
PS E:\python\codes> 
e:; cd 'e:\python\codes'; & 'C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe' 'c:\Users\yaho2\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '63060' '--' 'e:\python\codes\NadoCoding\test.py'
```

Comment: there is no problem; this is just VSCode opening a terminal and running your code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not describe an actual problem.

Comment: running the program in a debugger is always slow

Comment: @Veterans -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This path information is useful, it shows us the commands executed when VS Code runs python code. "cd" is to go to the parent folder of the executed python file. The called python executable program "python.exe", the debugger "debugpy" for debugging, and the executed python script.

You could use the green operation button provided by the "Python" extension, it will show less paths and therefore less running time.

In addition, you could also try to use VS Code related extensions, such as "Code Runner".

Comment: @Veterans -If my answer is useful, please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer to help others find this solution.

Comment: oh..could you let me know how to do that for you? Thanks!